# Use iTextSharp to merge several A5 pages into A4 pages

Tags: c#, itext

I generate several A5 pdfs and i now want to create a single batch pdf however the batch pdf will be A4 pages so i want to merge 2 of the pdfs per page.  How to i merge 2 A5 pdfs into a single A4 sheet.  I'm using iTextSharp to create the pdfs.

Comment: The question is incomplete. Define *merge*. Do you need the content to *reflow* or are you looking to *N-up* your document? The former is impossible in PDF (in general, not because you're using iTextSharp), the latter is explained in "iText in Action."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to *merge 2 A5 pdfs into a single A4 sheet* by arranging them side-by-side on there (aka 2-up), not by overlaying them, let alone reflowing them to a single page.

Using iTextSharp you can do that basing your code on [NUpTool.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=NUpTool) from the [Webified iTextSharp Examples](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/).

You have to change that sample somewhat, though, as it assumes the target format to be the same as the format of the source and scales down the source pages to make multiple pages fit.

Furthermore that sample by default stores its result documents in some ZIP file, so you'll have to take only the parts you need.

The sample is the C#ified version of [NUpTool.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115), an example from [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action, Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) which Bruno is the author of and which he referred to in his comment to your question.

This sample under the hood essentially does what @plinth described in his answer with the twist of wrapping the original page contents in individual form xobjects which allows it to leave the resources as they are.

Be aware, though, the sample only takes the page content, not the annotations from the original file. If you have e.g. AcroForm form fields which need to come along, the sample has to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable, but it's going to stink as there are a lot of things that can go horribly wrong.

I don't know iTextSharp well, but I know PDF well, so let me tell you the steps to doing this.

First, you need to be able to make a blank A4 page in the orientation you want.  This is easy.
Next, you need to be able to take the content stream and resources from a given A5 page and place it on one half of the A4 page in the correct orientation.  To do this, you will need to inject into the stream:

- gsave (the `q` operator)
- rotation/translation (the `cm`) operator

then you will need to copy in the existing content stream then follow it with a grestore (`Q` operator).

If you can do this, then you should be able to modify the code to do the same thing but translate the A5 content halfway over/up the A4 page.

This is all the easy stuff. Here's where it gets hard.  You need to be able to do this for two pages into the same target page **and** you need to merge the resources together.  That's the hard part.  It's hard because when PDF generation software makes pages and you decide to use a font, the font resource for that page will probably be named something useful, like `/F1`.  If both pages have an `F1` which do not reference the same font, you will need to rename one of them and change the content stream to reflect the remapping.  You will also need to do that for XObjects (Images and Forms), ColorSpace objects, Graphics State objects, Pattern objects and so on.

Comment: *you need to merge the resources together* - if you wrap the former page contents in a form xobject each, you don't need to merge resources.